# Bash - Variables - bash -c command

Tags: bash, variables

I'm pretty new to bash and I would need help with understanding these two lines of code. I already know how to assign a value to a variable and what command declare -p does. The main problem is with the bash -c command.

```
A=5; bash -c 'declare -p A'; declare -p A

A=7 bash -c 'declare -p A'; declare -p A
```

Comment: note that `A=5; bash...` is different than `A=7 bash ...` (I'm not talking about the 5 or 7). the `;` char means "end of statement", but when there is no `;` char, an assignment like `A=7` before any command, means "create this variable/value and use it inside of the command" (in this case `bash`. Not really clear what the point of the code you have included is, anything outside of the single-quotes, ie. `declare -p A` (the 2nd time), is evaluated by the local shell, and not the `bash -c` invocation. ....

Comment: If you're trying to solve a real problem, please include small set of sample inputs, required output from that sample, the current sample output AND the exact text of any errors or warning messages. I would say this is not the sort of problem to be learning about bash scripting. Find a real problem to solve ;-)  Good luck.